# Lightbox not working on subdirectory

Tags: html, css, lightbox

I relatively new to bootstrap in general. I am currently working on a site. On the main site, lightbox works. When I put it in a subdirectory it ceases to work.

My directory structure is as follows.

PUBLIC
- css
- images
- other php files
- SECONDARY SITE
  *+ css

  + images

  + other php files*

If I move any of the files from the PUBLIC main site (where bootstrap works) to the SECONDARY SITE lightbox ceases to work.

Whenever I do the opposite, from SECONDARY SITE to PUBLIC main, it all of sudden works.

Im pretty much using the same code on both sites. I made sure that the links were pointing to the right sites.

Here are my definitions.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/defined.css">
<link href="css/ekko-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/ekko-lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="css/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="css/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).ekkoLightbox();
});

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="center"><a href="images/tm_application_swatches/tm01.jpg" data-title="IMAGE NAME" data-toggle="lightbox"><img class="thumbnail" height="250" style="display:inline" src="images/tm_application_swatches/tm01.jpg"></a><p></p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

On Chrome's Developer Tools it caught this.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.lightbox_body.htmll is not a function
    at b.showLoading (ekko-lightbox.min.js:7)
    at new b (ekko-lightbox.min.js:7)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (ekko-lightbox.min.js:7)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.a.fn.ekkoLightbox (ekko-lightbox.min.js:7)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (tm_swatch.php:22)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

I'm out of ideas, your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you correctly but why would you want to put any dependency to a subsite instead of pointing to an upper level directory when referencing from a subsite?

Comment: Hi Adam, its not a dependency. The Public (Main site) uses the first css, while the Second site has its own css folder. the second is not dependent of the first. If I remove the first css, the second will still stand and vice versa.

Comment: Just to be clear, the main site has the following folders in it CSS | Images | SECONDARY SITE. In the secondary site it has its own CSS and Images folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative links like `href="css..`, but most likely you need to have root-relative links, like `href="/css`

Comment: I hoped you would double check your paths (all of them) and adjust them if necessary.